# How to connect lambda with self-hosted kafka

Tags: amazon-lambda

I am trying to connect kafka and aws lambda on a different hosting provider. When I connect via AWS EC2, it works fine because they are in the same VPC, but when I try to connect kafka and lambda on a different hosting provider, it does not work for the following reason.

```
Last processing result: PROBLEM: Connection error. Please check your event source connection configuration. If your event source lives in a VPC, try setting up a new Lambda function or EC2 instance with the same VPC, Subnet, and Security Group settings. Connect the new device to the Kafka cluster and consume messages to ensure that the issue is not related to VPC or Endpoint configuration. If the new device is able to consume messages, please contact Lambda customer support for further investigation.
```

I'm currently set up to access the internet by connecting a subnet to my internet gateway, but I can't connect this way?

Reference links

- https://aws.amazon.com/ko/blogs/compute/using-self-hosted-apache-kafka-as-an-event-source-for-aws-lambda/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kafka.html#services-kafka-vpc-config